# IdentityServer 4 with .net Core Identity : publishing code update on Azure makes refresh tokens invalid despite the use of data protection

Tags: azure, identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity, refresh-token, data-protection

I have setup an IdentityServer 4 API in which I use .Net Core Identity for managing the users. As part of this setup, I use JWT tokens for controlling access to our APIs in combination of refresh tokens to renew the JWT when needed.

All works like a charm until I do a code update and do a republish on Azure App Service. As from that point, the refresh tokens no longer work and all users have to re-login which is a real pain. I looked everywhere on the web without being able to find a solution. I do use Data Protection for persisting the keys in a blob storage but that does not seem to do anything.

Can anybody help me as I am stuck in a situation where I avoid to do any code update so my users won't be frustrated. Thanks in advance.

Here is my ConfigureServices in startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
        {
            // Default Lockout settings.
            options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
            options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

            // Default Password settings.
            options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 1;
            options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;

            // Default User settings.
            options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+"; //must be email characters if taken as username
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
        {
            options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
            options.PublicOrigin = Configuration["Domains:PublicOrigin"];
            options.IssuerUri = Configuration["Domains:Authority"];
        })
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApis())
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients(Configuration))
            .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddProfileService<MyProfileService>();

        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(isAuth =>
            {
                isAuth.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                isAuth.Authority = Configuration["Domains:Authority"];
                isAuth.ApiName = "identity_api";
            });

        X509Certificate2 certificate = CertificateHelper.GetCertificate(Configuration, Environment);

        var connectionString = Configuration["CloudStorageAccount:ConnectionString"];
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
        var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("tokens");

        container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        services.AddDataProtection()
            .PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage(container, Configuration["KeyVault:AzureBlobKeysFileIfNotKubernetes"])
            .ProtectKeysWithCertificate(certificate)
            .SetApplicationName("AppIdentity");

        builder.AddSigningCredential(certificate);

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }
```

Comment: It seems you are using InMemory configuration for everything.. I expect that these will be removed/added whenever you republish?

Comment: @Anonymous if you do reference the .AddInMemory methods from IdentityServer 4, I don't think they are related to the refresh tokens ....

Comment: Anybody ? No help ;( ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the configuration of the Operational Store for Identity Server.

```
builder.AddOperationalStore(options => 
   options.ConfigureDbContext = storeBuilder => storeBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
);
```

Without this Identity Server doesn't know where to store the refresh tokens so that they are available after the application restarts.

Take a look at [Operational Store support for persisted grants](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/ef.html#operational-store-support-for-persisted-grants) for more information.